# Освобождение ресурсов WinSock

Tags: windows, c, winsock, c++

Стартует сервер и несколько клиентов. После непродолжительного времени, от клиентов перестают приходить данные, т.е. сначала все норм, потом, все одновременно подвисают. После перезапуска сервера, все повторяется по новой. Сианс клиента с сервером заключается в:

1. Открытие сокета
2. Передачи данных на сервер
3. Приема данных с сервера
4. Закрытие сокета

На сервере все сокеты закрываются. Закрываю так:

```
shutdown(sock, SD_BOTH);
closesocket(sock);
```

В чем может быть ошибка? Как будт-то не освобождаю что-то.

UPD Заметил такую закономерность: в начале все работает норм, затем что-то происходит и клиенты пишут ошибку, через некоторое время, без перезапуска сервера, все повторятеся вновь. Нормальное соединение, ошибка и опять нормальное.

UPD 2 Отрабатывает чуть больше 16 тысяч сеансов. Потом пишет ошибку (10055) при создании сокета в течении 1-2 тысячи попыток (я думаю там завязка навремя). Потом опять более 16 тысяч успешных сеансов.

Возможно, какой-то системный буффер необходимо освободить руками?

Comment: А Вы ждете ответа от сокета, или отправили данные и забыли? Скажем, функцию select используете?

Comment: Жду. Обе стороны принимают и отправляют данные.

Comment: А если таймаут уменьшить?

Comment: Хм... Не совсем понял вас. Я выбираю данные ф-ей 'select'

Comment: Но Вы же ждете ответ от сокета. Если уменьшить время ожидания? Ну, в ф-ции select последний параметр. Например, заполнить структуру timeval и передать её адрес той же функции.
UPD. И попробуйте уменьшить число ожидаемых сокетов. Хоть это и нагрузка на сеть, но все же...

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, ошибка не в программе, а в настройках сервера. Читайте по Вашей ошибке [тут](http://www.proxyplus.cz/faq/articles/EN/art10002.htm).
И потом, на сервере антивирусы, ускорители, брандмауеры стоят? И снова-таки, попробуйте уменьшить таймаут сокета, т.е. например, если через 10мс. не будет ответа -- закрывайте порт, удаляйте сокет, уступайте место другому сокету. Примерно так. Заодно: сам сервак такую интенсивность выдерживает? Попробуйте уменьшить к-во сокетов в целом.

Comment: Уменьшение таймаута ничего не дает. Приятие решения о закрытии сокета я делаю при возникновении ошибки. В системе есть клиенты, которые несколько раз отправляют данные во время сеанса. Параметор backlog, то же не влияет. Как я понял, это поведение обьясняется параметром stacksize библиотеки winsock2. Остается  только научиться определять, когда стек полный и освобождать его. И еще ворос, почему он вообще переполняется? Я же закрываю сокеты.

Comment: Попробуйте создавать сокеты динамически, и так же -- удалять. И потом, Вы наверняка освобождаете порт при удалении сокета. А используется ли он после этого? Возможно, он у Вас все ещё считается открытым... А сокеты Вы создаете как? Массивом, или очередью?

Comment: Сокеты создаются динамическм, очередью. Я освобождаю только сокет полученный при вызове ф-и accept (не понял про порт).

Comment: Можете показать код создания сокета, отправки/приема данных от сокета, и удаления его? Возможно, не хватает некоторых функций для проверки, так с ходу я сказать не могу.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть при каждом получении нового сокета из  **accept()** сколько у Вас еще незакрытых сокетов, попечатайте в лог. 

Может быть картина прояснится.

Comment: Смотрел. От 1 до 7.